# How to make a drone pipeline to be run when another ignored pipeline got in failure

Tags: pipeline, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, drone.io

I have a pipeline in my *.drone.yml* file which its failures will be ignored in this way:

**.drone.yml**

```
- name: 'My ignored pipeline'
failure: ignore
```

Now I need another pipeline to be run when the 1st pipeline got into failure.
I did it in this way:

**.drone.yml**

```
- name: 'My ignored pipeline'
failure: ignore

- name: 'Follow up pipeline'
...related configs...
when:
  status:
    - failure
depends_on:
- My ignored pipeline
```

But it doesn't work, because it can not detect any failure in the 1st pipeline.
Can anybody help me with what should I do to fix this problem? or any other solution for this problem?